# Enter and Backspace not working with Slate.js editor in React

Tags: reactjs, event-listener, slatejs

I am implementing a text editor for an application and am trying to add some hot keys for quick editing like **bold** and *italics*.  For some reason after I implement my onKeyDown listener to render my formatted text my backspace and enter buttons no longer work. The `onChange` handler doesn't get fired when the keys are backspace or enter, but does get fired for every other key.  Here is my code below.

`TextEditor.js`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Editor } from 'slate-react';
import { Value } from 'slate';
import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
import { bold } from 'react-icons-kit/feather/bold';
import { italic } from 'react-icons-kit/feather/italic';
import { BoldMark, ItalicMark } from './TextComponents/index';
import FormatToolbar from './FormatToolbar/FormatToolbar';

const initialValue = Value.fromJSON({
  document: {
    nodes: [
      {
        object: 'block',
        type: 'paragraph',
        nodes: [
          {
            object: 'text',
            text: 'My first paragraph!'
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
});

class TextEditor extends Component {
  state = {
    value: initialValue
  }

  onKeyDown = (e, change) => {
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
      console.log('[I am not a control key]');
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('[e key]', e.key);
    switch (e.key) {
      case 'b': {
        change.toggleMark('bold');
        return true;
      }
      case 'i': {
        change.toggleMark('italic');
        return true;
      }
      default: {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  renderMark = props => {
    const { type } = props.mark;

    switch (type) {
      case 'bold':
        return <BoldMark {...props} />;
      case 'italic':
        return <ItalicMark {...props} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  onChange = ({ value }) => {
    console.log('[on change]');
    this.setState({
      value
    });
  }

  render () {
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <FormatToolbar>
          <button type="button" className="tooltip-icon-button">
            <Icon icon={bold} />
          </button>
          <button type="button" className="tooltip-icon-button">
            <Icon icon={italic} />
          </button>
        </FormatToolbar>
        <Editor
          value={value}
          onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          renderMark={this.renderMark}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

I am following along this tutorial https://www.strilliant.com/2018/07/15/let%E2%80%99s-build-a-fast-slick-and-customizable-rich-text-editor-with-slate-js-and-react/

I can't seem to find what I have done differently and am wondering if there was a change to slate/react that is blocking the code I'm following from working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using the same tutorial and having this issue I would refer to the docs for Slate.js

https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/adding-event-handlers

`Correct code`

```
  onKeyDown = (e, editor, next) => {
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
      return next();
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    switch (e.key) {
      case 'b': {
        editor.toggleMark('bold');
        return true;
      }
      case 'i': {
        editor.toggleMark('italic');
        return true;
      }
      default: {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Slate 2.0 deprecated `change` and now uses `editor`.  Make sure to declare the `next` parameter and call that on your return if your hot key is not pressed (in my case control).